# How to avoid debconf questions during apt install (lightdm)?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, debconf

On my Xenial test system, I've got already gdm3 installed. Now I'd like to install the lightdm package as well. When I do so, it asks which default display manager should be used:

[image: Configuring lightdm - debconf]

I need to avoid this question (going to install those packages with Chef). How do I do that?

With `debconf-get-selections`, I found:

```
$ debconf-get-selections | grep lightdm
# Choices: gdm3, lightdm
lightdm shared/default-x-display-manager    select  gdm3
lightdm lightdm/daemon_name string  /usr/sbin/lightdm
```

Based on that, I created a file with an answer and gave it to `debconf-set-selections`:

```
$ cat /tmp/lightdm
lightdm shared/default-x-display-manager select lightdm

$ sudo debconf-set-selections -v /tmp/lightdm
info: Trying to set 'shared/default-x-display-manager' [select] to 'lightdm'
info: Loading answer for 'shared/default-x-display-manager'
```

But when I now run `apt install lightdm`, it still asks this question.

Why is it still asking that question and how can I avoid that?

Comment: You should be able to set the underlying `debconf` frontend mode to noninteractive as shown here [apt-get install without debconf prompt](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106553/65304)

Comment: The lightdm package does not honor DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive. I have not tried with debconf. Reported bug is still open: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1616905